# How to sum elements of a table in cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a table with one of the columns having a numerical value. How to find a sum of all the values in that column and verify that it is equal to value from another column?

```
<div>
   <p>Total age</p>
   <span id="totalAge">144</span>
</div> 
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to verify that total age is equal to sum of ages.

Comment: Please post the HTML DOM or add the html code.

Comment: Added html code of similar structure. Don't know how to write code in cypress for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to extract the 3rd cell of each row, map the elements to their text, convert to numeric, and reduce to a total.

Cypress provides the lodash library `Cypress._` which has useful helpers

- `Cypress_.map()` for converting elements to text and text to numbers
- `Cypress_.sum()` for reducing an array of numbers to a total

See [Sorting the Table](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/07/27/sorting-the-table/) for some background.

```js
// Reusable helpers from lodash functions
const toStrings = (cells$) => Cypress._.map(cells$, 'textContent')
const toNumbers = (texts) => Cypress._.map(texts, Number)
const sum = (numbers) => Cypress._.sum(numbers)

cy.get('td:nth-child(3)')
.then(toStrings)           // use .then() to apply the helpers to all elements
.then(toNumbers)
.then(sum)
.then(cellsTotal => {
  cy.get('#totalAge')
  .then(toStrings)
  .then(toNumbers)
  .then(sum)
  .should('eq', cellsTotal)  // after data transformed, simple assertion
})
```

---

**Flow**

If you want to compose multiple functions into one, use `Cypress._.flow()`

```js
const toStrings = (cells$) => Cypress._.map(cells$, 'textContent')
const toNumbers = (texts) => Cypress._.map(texts, Number)
const sum = (numbers) => Cypress._.sum(numbers)

const sumAgeValues = Cypress._.flow([toStrings, toNumbers, sum])

cy.get('td:nth-child(3)')
.then(sumAgeValues)
.then(cellsTotal => {
  cy.get('#totalAge')
  .then(sumAgeValues)
  .should('eq', cellsTotal)  // after data transformed, simple assertion
})
```

---

**Filtering**

You can also use lodash to select the numeric cells

- `Cypress._.isFinite()` checks text equates to a number
- `Cypress._.filter()` selects cells that meet the criteria

```js
const isNumeric = (cell) => Cypress._.isFinite(+cell.textContent)
const filterNumeric = (cells$) => Cypress._.filter(cells$, isNumeric)

const toStrings = (cells$) => Cypress._.map(cells$, 'textContent')
const toNumbers = (texts) => Cypress._.map(texts, Number)
const sum = (numbers) => Cypress._.sum(numbers)

const sumAgeValues = Cypress._.flow([toStrings, toNumbers, sum])

cy.get('td')           // don't need exact column position
.then(filterNumeric)
.then(sumAgeValues)
.then(cellsTotal => {
  cy.get('#totalAge')
  .then(sumAgeValues)
  .should('eq', cellsTotal) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
let sum = 0;
cy.get('td:nth-child(3)').each(($ele) => {
  sum = sum + +($ele.text())
})
cy.get('#totalAge').invoke('text').then((totalAge) => {
  expect(+totalAge).to.equal(sum)
})
```